# Como gerar um programa executável em python

Tags: python, compilação

Comecei a ver linguagens de programação a um certo tempo, atualmente estou aprendendo Python, JavaScript e outras.

E gostaria de saber como que posso gerar um programa independente do interpretador? Quero dizer, gerar um executável.

Comment: Desculpa, sou novo nesse fórum! Não tinha ideia do que colocar nas tags e coloquei essas daí. Minha dúvida é: como criar um executável em python, por exemplo, que abra fora do editor.

Comment: @RafaelRibeiroSilva O que você quer dizer com "abrir fora do editor"? Não tá fazendo sentido pra mim.

Comment: @MarceloBoni É isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependendo do aplicativo programas como `cx_Freeze` e `PyInstaller` costumam ser boas opções para gerar executáveis:

**Cx_Freeze**

http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

**PyInstaller**

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigado!